# show selectpicker after rendering

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a couple of selectpicker elements in a form and they take about 0.5 sec to render. This is fine with me, but until they have been rendered they mess up my html structure. So I would like to only show them after they have been rendered.
My approach was as follows. I set all selectpicker elements to display:none and added the following javascript code

```
$("#state_selection").selectpicker();
$("#country_selection").selectpicker();
document.getElementById('state_selection_element').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('country_selection_element').style.display = '';
```

this basically did what I wanted. Except of two issues:

(1) It is suboptimal, since the render command forces the form to render again after the page load. Since the render takes about 0.5sec its not ideal. There should be a better way

(2) The render is somehow messing up the position of my feedback validation tick box. It now show the feedback within the selectpicker instead of to the right of it.

The ideal solution would be to show the selectpicker only after the initial page rendering... any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
$('#state_selection').on('rendered.bs.select', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('state_selection_element').style.display = '';
});
$('#country_selection').on('rendered.bs.select', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('country_selection_element').style.display = '';
});
```